# PyTorch loads old data when using tensorboard

Tags: pytorch, tensorboard

In using tensorboard I have cleared my data directory and trained a new model but I am seeing images from an old model. Why is tensorboard loading old data, where is it being stored, and how do I remove it?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Here is my repo: [link](https://github.com/adomakor412/NERTO_CIMSS_GOES-R/blob/9fb70379312bda606badc222a3318cbefba1f470/AUC_model.ipynb). You'll see an error for 3 channels where the algorithm calls for 1 channel. I've changed my image files but I still it crashing for the old images. In my terminal I have the following running: tensorboard _--logdir='./NERTO_CIMSS_GOES-R/' --bind_all --port=6006 &_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tensorboard was built to have caches in case long training fails you have "bak"-like files that your board will generate visualizations from. Unfortunately, there is not a good practice to manually remove hidden temp files as they are not seen from displaying files including ones with the . (dot) prefix using bash. This memory is self-managed. For best practices, (1) have your tensorboard name be dynamic for results of each run: this can be done using datetime library in combination with an f-string in python so that the name of each run is separated by a time stamp. (This command be done right from python, say a jupyter notebook, if you import the **subprocess** package and run your bash command straight from the script.) (2) Additionally, you are strongly advised to save your logdir (log directory) separately from where you are running the code. These two practices together should solve all the problems related to tmp files erroneously populating new results.

[How to "reset" tensorboard data after killing tensorflow instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34454721/how-to-reset-tensorboard-data-after-killing-tensorflow-instance)